# cat all files except a select few

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, bash-scripting

If there some particular syntax so that I can `cat` all files in a directory, except for the select ones. For eg., suppose I have ~1200 text files containing some lines, about 3 or 4 lines per file, except there are a few files:

```
readme.md
contrib.rst
licence.txt
```

which are longer. I want to view the contents of all files except the 3 (or if possible, more) files mentioned above.

I tried the following command:

```
cat !{readme.md,contrib.rst,licence.txt}*.*
```

because I saw somewhere a usage of `cat` as follows:

```
cat [!t][!m][!p]*.sh
```

I thought that since, `{a,b}` means a set in bash-scripts, negating that should work. Of course I was wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this with bash's extended pattern matching feature:

```
shopt -s extglob
cat !(readme.md|contrib.rst|licence.txt)
```

Comment: I prefer this one because it didn't modify GLOBIGNORE.  Less _shell invasive_  :-)

Answer (score 2):

Try this with bash:

```
GLOBIGNORE="readme.md:contrib.rst:licence.txt"
cat *
unset GLOBIGNORE
```

Comment: Nice one. And matching the OPs request for the specific shell. +1

Comment: Better the other one, you should erase (forget) the previous value of GLOBIGNORE.

Answer (score 1):

What did you already try?

Are it always the same files which you want to skip.

In that case you could hardcode them in a command. E.g. something like
`find ! -name readme.md -o ! -name contrib.rst -o ! -name licence.txt -exec cat {} \+`

Now if you want something which skips all files larger than 4 lines without knowing the file names beforehand then the solution will obviously get more complex. In that case please edit your post.

Comment: You don't need to escape the `+`.

Comment: Unconcious habit  from `\;`  :(

Answer (score 1):

**Without modifying the current shell setting** it's possible to execute each of the Cyrus proposal in a subshell

```
(GLOBIGNORE="readme.md:contrib.rst:licence.txt" ; cat *)
```

as well as

```
(shopt -s extglob; cat !(readme.md|contrib.rst|licence.txt))
```